# Laravel 5.7 Page renders fine but shows 500 error at the bottom

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a Laravel 5.7 site.  It renders all the pages and routes fine but at the bottom shows the following error:

> 500  Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.

All views are closed by a shared `footer.blade.php` file that is properly closed with html.  The server is a **LAMP server** with **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Apache2**, **Php 7.2**

When I looked into the HTML generated by the browser, it seems like as if Laravel is inserting a 500 page at the bottom of my code.

While I close  my html with /body and /html tags it automatically inserts doctype html html lang="en" head title Error title tags along with remainder of the 500 page.

[image]

Comment: You can get this error for many reasons, please give more information.

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya  - the image above is the bottom of every view.  All the views render fine.  This error is rather strange.  If you look carefully, the closure of header is in grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was a file permission issue**.

So By Giving the `0777` Access to `Storage` Directory Fixed it

Following commands resolved the issue.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```